# Firebase UI loading box

Tags: android, firebase, firebaseui

When you launch FirebaseUI using intent, for a second you can see a popup showing you information that it's loading. Is there a way to change the message and style of the popup?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the loading message by [overriding that string](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/auth/README.md#strings) on your strings.xml file:

```
<resources>
    <string name="fui_progress_dialog_signing_up">Creating your shiny new account...</string>
</resources>
```

And you can change the style popup by [creating a theme](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/auth/README.md#themes) that has FirebaseUI as it's parent:

```
<style name="GreenTheme" parent="FirebaseUI">
    <!-- Required for sign-in flow styling -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/material_green_500</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/material_green_700</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/material_purple_a700</item>

    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/material_green_500</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/material_lime_a700</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/material_green_a200</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/material_green_50</item>
</style>
```

Please refer to the [FirebaseUI Github](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/auth/README.md#ui-customization) to see the full UI customization guide.